# Should this question about touching event horizons really be closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

The question [If two black hole event horizons overlap (touch) can they ever separate again?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32410/7982) is well received with +32 upvotes currently and has two well received answers with +32 and +24 votes as well.

There are now two votes to close as duplicate of [highspeed black holes or neutron stars on (almost) head-on collision course and kinetic energy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13551/7982) where votes on the question and its two answers added together are +3. +5 and +2 respectively.

The new "event horizons overlap" question and its answers have all generated substantial, on-topic high-level discourse in comments as well.

I wonder if the first vtc as duplicate simply found something that sounded related *and was older* without attention to the relative quality. Based on votes alone, if one felt to dupe anything one might chose to vtc *in the opposite direction*.

The topic is sophisticated and I can't judge the degree of overlap to make any call about the necessity of closing either question as duplicate of the other, but I think the current vote is unproductive and will steer attention away from some very well received posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions and answers are extremely correlated to the degree I would feel uncomfortable unilaterally reversing a close action, but I agree both discussions seem helpful. Just keep tabs on it, and it if gets closed cast a reopen vote. Duplicates don't go away anyway.